# Install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11 on MSI with NVMe controller

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, msi

Good morning, I am planning to install ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11 on MSI Prestige 15 A12UC following this guide:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dual-booting-windows-10-with-ubuntu-16-04-mission-msi-1efd3e131dc

I have some questions:

**1. Is this guide ok, even if my first OS on the PC is Windows11?**

**2. If I disable fast startup, will the pc turn on considerably slower? Is this really needed?**

**3. I checked on system information that I have BIOS mode UEFI. When creating the bootable USB, should I select *GPT* and *UEFI (non CSM)* ?**

My colleagues, when partitioning a different PC model, had to switch from RAID to AHCI to make dual boot working, and to disable Bitlocker as well. I have NVMe controller on my notebook.

**4. Should I do any similar procedure to switch controller or mine is ok?**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just to clairify:  "Fast Startup" is a Windows Power option (well hidden), which basically hibernates the machine when you shutdown, and skips the actual boot process when turned back on -- Required to be disabled.  "Fast Boot" is just a BIOs/UEFI Settings option to slow down the boot to allow you to hit an option button, like device to boot or UEFI Settings, not required, but makes life easier for you when off if you need any options.

Answer (score 0):

Q1, The guide is largely ok, it shows the main steps but you should research installation alongside Windows 11. The guide is quite old and you should consider Ubuntu 22.04. instead of 20.04 unless you have a particular reason for that choice. I think there are some potential complications when installing alongside Windows 11 that you should be aware of. I’ve no experience of that myself.

Q2. You need to disable fast startup especially if you want to access the Windows partition from Ubuntu. When you shutdown Windows with fast startup turned on it will effectively hibernate and not actually shutdown. This means the disk is locked so it cannot be accessed. On a modern computer with an nvme drive this doesn’t add too much to the boot time. You can test this out before you install Ubuntu to see if that is a showstopper for you.

Q3. You should choose GPT and UEFI.

Q4. You haven’t provided any info to answer this one. Are you using either RAID or bitlocker?

Hope this helps